# Comparing adverbs in comparative and superlative forms

Tags: comparatives, superlative-degree

Comparing with adverbs in comparative or superlative form: When would us louder / loudest and when would you use more loudly / most loudly

Comment: Sorry I can't resist linking [Peanuts](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/GImAsRrgYQZXRgHz38buosgnElKZIUu44FEX6k4oN0rM16k2-EYf8helUaRmYEGjUhtXEg9EV3FWybsRWjCScj0sLO4b0kYU_rMCOYZ7dA)

Comment: Peanuts has become 403 error.

Answer (score -1):

The words "louder" and "loudest" are the comparative and superlative forms of the **adjective** "loud." Adjectives are used to describe nouns.
The terms "more loudly" and "most loudly" are the comparative and superlative forms of the **adverb** "loudly." Adverbs are used to describe verbs. (There are some other kinds of adverbs, but they aren't important for this discussion because they don't have comparatives and superlatives.)

Comment: There also exist "loudlier" and "loudliest" for the adverb.

Comment: My nearest dictionary lists "loud" as both adjective and adverb. I've certainly often heard things like "I can yell louder than you" with no reaction from my bad-grammar reflex.